# Group Signature Scheme without Opening but with Revocation

Tags: signature, anonymity

After reading many papers about [group signature schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_signature), I saw that basically all of them employ the possibility of "signature opening": The Group Manager (GM) can identify any signature made by his group's members. But I would like to completely eradicate that feature and rather revoke group members by their public key/ID token, preserving signature anonymity at all times.

(I am thinking about very dynamic and large groups with their members "expiring" after a certain time: the GM keeps a public key list and revokes keys when they expire. Maybe existing cryptography is not scalable enough for that yet, though.)

An option would be to take a GSS that seperates the issuer GM and the opener GM and just throw away the opener's key. But that gives me two issues:

- Firstly, the users should stay anonymous even if the GM (the server) is compromised.
- Secondly, existing GSS do not actually seperate the opener's and the revoker's key, but since I need to revoke users' access rights, this is unfeasible.

Is there any such GSS that satisfies my security requirements? Are there any existing GSS that I could alter a little bit to remove the opening ability - preserving their security proof - and use? Are there entirely other options?

(The actual problem giving me headaches is more general security related and I didn't want to explain it here because it is rather complex. But if you have any further questions about my requirements, please go ahead!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If members "expiring" is the *only* reason for revocation, then you could just skip the whole "standard signature scheme" part of the following, encode the expiration dates into the IDs, and have the signers' arguments include that issue too.)

Well, there's always the generic approach:

- the GM generates a common reference string for an otherwise-noninterative [computationally witness-indistinguishable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness-indistinguishable_proof) system that is [co-sound](http://books.google.com/books?id=DIxCPUBmzlAC&pg=PA288) as a stand-alone argument of knowledge; i.e., it's infeasible to give a valid argument for any statement that it would be infeasible to know a witness for
- the GM chooses a function from a collision-resistant hash family
- the GM generates a two inner key-pairs, one for a standard signature scheme
  and one for an identity-based signature scheme
- the GSS's public key is the ordered quadruple whose entries are
  the common reference string and the collision-resistant hash function and the inner public keys
- the GM's private key is the ordered pair whose entries are the inner private keys
- the GM uses the standard signature scheme for signing [the root hash of a [Merkle tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) of the *result of sorting* the revoked identities] along with [other information, such as a date], and regularly gives out that signature along with that sorted list, similarly to how [CRLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revocation_list) are issued in standard implementations of PKI
- for users issuing and verifying signatures, let "the sro" denote the most recent version known to the signer of the previous bullet point's signature together with [the root hash ... revoked identities] and the specified other information
- the GM issues for the GSS by issuing for the identity-based signature scheme
- users sign by generating a key-pair for a [strongly unforgeable one-time signature (OTS) scheme](http://books.google.com/books?id=mH3MZMnW-JAC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7), choosing enough information to specify what Identity Revocation List to use, arguing knowledge of a signature on the OTS verification key by an identity and two branches through the tree witnessing that the identity is not on the list, using the OTS signing key to sign the ordered triple whose entries are **the sro** and **the argument** and **the message**, and letting the signature be the ordered quadruple whose entries are **the sro** and **the OTS verification key** and **the argument** and **the OTS signature**
- receivers verify by verifying the signature on the sro, verifying that its "other information" is appropriate (specifically, it's date is recent enough), verifying the argument for the sro and the OTS verification key and the message, and then verifying the OTS signature

The main problem with this approach is the size of the witness-indistinguishable arguments.

If you use the modification of [figure 3 in this link](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/J.Groth/NIZKJournal.pdf#page=15) obtained by replacing $K_{\text{binding}}$ with $K_{\text{hiding}}$,

then the existence of a witness that the commitment key is hiding suffices for perfect anonymity.

Thus, you could have the GM keep such a witness and give
[concurrent zero-knowledge proofs](http://www.cs.illinois.edu/~mmp/pub/PRS.pdf) that such a witness exists.

There are apparently lots of [identity-based signature schemes that can work in bilinear groups](https://www.google.com/#q=%22identity-based+signature).

It is possible that the type of system described in [this paper](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/J.Groth/WImoduleFull.pdf) can be adapted to such a scheme. $\:$ Although I'm not sure, it seems likely that NIZK co-sound arguments constructed from the previous two sentences could provide the same anonymity as I mentioned in the previous paragraph.

[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.148.2036) gives a NIZK protocol with whose use in this approach comes with a trade-off:

soundness is based on the [generic bilinear group model](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/david.lubicz/articles/pseudo.pdf) (analogous to the Random Oracle Model),

but by having users verify the common reference string's structure as described on [page 3](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=6AD193071E8502F62E5BD0AF057D84A3?doi=10.1.1.148.2036&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=3),

perfect anonymity is guaranteed *without* needing to trust or interact with the GM.

I have not managed to come up with any scheme for what you

are asking about that does not use a non-interactive argument.

Comment: unfortunately, your strange linebreaks make some of your answers quite unreadable.

Comment: This does not make sense: "the GM issues for the GSS by issuing for the identity-based signature scheme" - could you please clarify?

Comment: Are you having difficulty parsing that? $\:$ It should be parsed as "the GM [issues for the GSS] by [issuing for the identity-based signature scheme]". $\:$ Alternatively, perhaps I should include a link that describes identity-based signature schemes. $\:$ I don't see anything else that might might be unclear about that bullet point. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky Thanks, it's clear now. One further question: You say that you don't know of any more efficient schemes - but before I delve into reading and implementing, what kind of efficiency can I expect, probably needing groups with N > 1000?

Comment: I just made some corrections to my answer which make me realize that there may be significantly more efficient, though largely similar, methods. $\:$ I'll write up something about those later today. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: (err, by "later today", I mean "probably less than 2 hours from now".) $\;$

Comment: (That took a lot longer than I'd thought it would, mostly because I was typing up a lot of stuff that became useless when I realized that Merkle Trees made things much more efficient.) $\:$ I have no idea what efficiency these options would achieve. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: So, let's take Jens Groth's paper ("Sub-linear size Pairing-based...") as an example. The GM publishes the identities of the group members in an ID-based Signature Scheme. The Statement (a1..an in the paper) would be "Identity I has signed OTS key pair O", the commitment and argument are transmitted to the verifier V. What do you mean by "two branches through the tree witnessing that the identity is not on the list"? How can V verify the actual signature on the OTS key by the GM? (Why can't anyone pretend to be in the group?)

Comment: I was blindly assuming that there were at least as many revoked identities as issued-but-not-revoked identities; although I now notice that your paragraph about expiration implies otherwise. $\:$ On the other hand, basing a construction resembling mine on the list of issued-but-not-revoked identities comes with a reduction in anonymity: if someone signs something between the GM issuing for a new user and the signing user learning that fact, then everyone can tell that the signature was not created by the new user. $\:$  $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Actually, I don't really need the revocation feature: as you suggested, expiring was the issue I needed revocation for, but if we use ID-based signatures, that is not an issue anyway. So let's remove the entire CRL feature. But my other question stays: "How can V verify the actual signature on the OTS key by the GM? (Why can't anyone pretend to be in the group?)"

Comment: If what I mentioned in my previous sentence is an acceptable price, then you should look up [ring signatures](https://www.google.com/#q=ring+signatures), especially because the GM might be able to provide a common reference string. $\:$ (For that strategy, the GM would generate the ring signature key-pairs on its own and issue them and regularly give out a signed list of issued-but-not-revoked ring signature verification keys along with their expiration times.) $\:$ (continued ...) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: (... continued) $\:$ If that privacy reduction is not acceptable, then I mean the largest identity on the list that's less than the user's identity and the smallest identity on the list that's greater than the user's identity, similarly to what is described in [section 3.3 on this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=XSRdc_26EPsC&pg=PA85#v=onepage&q&f=false). $\:$ (continued ...) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: (... continued) $\:$ There is only a "signature on the OTS key by the GM" insofar as there is a signature on the OTS key with the identity-based signature scheme for which the GM knows the master private key; the GM is not involved in the generation of the OTS key and has never before seen that key. $\:$ V does not directly verify the users' signatures on the OTS keys; V verifies the arguments of knowledge of such signatures. $\;\;\;\;$